# Suggestions for importing MySQL data into elasticsearch?

Tags: mysql, xml, import, elasticsearch

Basically I need to take data from mysql, transform it, and import it into elasticsearch. The transformations I need to do are quite basic; for instance, taking the first 155 chars of the existing Head Note and creating a string for an Html Meta Description.  I have some good tools to go from MySQL to XML, but I don't know if that helps anything.

I've been looking around for an hour or so and can imagine several potential paths.  Perhaps there are better ones out there too.

1. Create XML from MySQL.  Use logstash (if possible?) to transform and import into Elasticsearch.
2. MySQL to XML.  Create XSLT file to restructure data.  Generate XML and somehow import into ES.
3. MySQL to XML.  Create XSLT file to restructure data.  Generate JSON and somehow import into ES.
4. Use river-jdbc plugin to import from MySQL, *IF* I can also join tables and transform data.
5. Other?

What would be an efficient way to import my data?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about it too simply, but I'd write a script to SELECT the data you want from MySQL and prepare it for the ElasticSearch Bulk API for the inserts.  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: (1) should be out of question. Do not use logstash for importing. The best way is to do what @AlainCollins suggested using a SELECT statement and perform the import. (4) might be a good solution as well. Good luck!